# Z-index CSS problem with different layers on fixed navbar

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with a navigation and a breadcrumb navigation bar.
if i use a dropdown to open other links he opens the drop menu behind the breadcrumbnav
How can i put this dropdown link before the breadcrumb navigation

The Breadcrumb must be in front of the body, so that breadcrumb & Navi are always on top

**HTML, CSS, JS**:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>CSS Layers</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class='backgr'>
    <div id='nbar' class='topnav'><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ShowMenu('bubble');">Dropdown Link</a>
            <div id='bubble' class='hidden'>
            <a href='#'>Sublink 1</a><br />
            <a href='#'>Sublink 2</a><br />
            <a href='#'>Sublink 3</a>
            </div></div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div class='tophid'>Link1 / Link2 / Link3</div>
    <br /><br />
    </div>
    
    <div class='content'>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>


    <style>
    BODY{
        margin:0px;
        }
        #nbar{
        position:fixed;
        heigzht:80px;
        background-color:#DDD;
        width:100%;
        padding:20px;
        }
        .backgr{
        background-color:#fff;
        position:fixed;
        z-index:0;
        height:100px;
        width:100%;
        }
        .tophid
        {
        position:fixed;
        background-color:#ffc900;
        padding:7px;
        width:100%;
        opacity:0.50;
        }
        .content{
        height:120%;
        z-index:-1;
        }
        #bubble{
        z-index:4;
        
        }
        .hidden{
        display:none;
        }
    </style>


    <script language='javascript'>
    function ShowMenu(id,out=''){
    
    if($('#' + id).hasClass('hidden'))
    {   
     $('#' + id).show();
     $('#' + id).removeClass('hidden');
     }
     else{
     $('#' + id).hide();
     $('#' + id).addClass('hidden');
     }
     }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add z-index:-1 to tophid

```
.tophid {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ffc900;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.50;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: No problem @Asario, remember to mark as accepted if it solved your problem.